# jQuery to add delay to menu navigation, usability

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Similar to whats found in superfish, Ive used this to add a slight delay to the hover effect on my CSS menu. Thought I would share and see if there might be suggestions for tuning it.

```
$('ul#nav li').hover(function(){
    var timer = $(this).data('timer');
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).addClass('over');
},function(){
    var li = $(this);
    li.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){ li.removeClass('over'); }, 500));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick thoughts/ideas re tuning:

As you have an id selector, it's far more efficient to go straight to that selector as the starting point. Also it's more efficient to find the child element rather than have everything combined in a single selector.

I also wouldn't bother with a timer when you can chain .delay instead. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so I posted the following example to give a gist of how you might use .delay. This is untested but basically you've got your long delay before the class adding the menu appears and it's removed after another long delay when focus is lost. You could alternatively use [slideDown and slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) or [fadeIn and fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) for a nice effect.

I also added a check to the part that adds the class as folks can move in and out of menus much faster than the delay given. That probably could do with some more thought.

```
$('#nav').find('li')
.hover(function()
{
    if (!$(this).hasClass('over'))
    {
        $(this).delay(500).addClass('over');
    }
})
.blur(function()
{
    $(this).delay(500).removeClass('over');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul#nav  {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul#nav li  {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
ul#nav li a  {
 display: block;
}
ul#nav li a:hover  {

}
ul#nav li ul  {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
        padding: 0px;
        z-index: 100; /* if slider */
}
ul#nav li:hover ul  {
 display: block;
}
ul#nav li:hover ul li ul {
 display: none;
}
ul#nav li ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}
ul#nav li ul li  {
 clear: left;
}
ul#nav li ul li a  {

}
```